# Как написать код на Python, чтобы можно было ввести только корректный возраст например от 1 до ста, если писать больше то выбивало ошибку

Tags: python

Не знаю как написать программу, в которую при вводе возраста от 1 до 100 было указано, что это правильно. При вводе иных числовых значений выводилась ошибка.
Моя попытка выглядит так:

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print('Круто')
if range not True:
    print('Введите свой корректный возраст')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
age = int(input('Num from 1 to 100 '))
if 1 <= age <=100:
    print("Cool")
else:
    print("Bad")
```

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите с `range`, то вот такой вариант:

```py
while True:
    age = int(input('Введите возраст: '))
    if age in range(1, 101):
        print('Круто')
        break
    else:
        print('Введите свой корректный возраст')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, тут конечно вы совсем обленились ... Оператор for  запускает у  вас просто цикл от 1 до 99.

```
 age = int(input('введите возраст'))
 if (age >= 1) and (age <= 100):
     print('Вы ввели корректное значение')
 else:
     print('Вы обманщик!')
```

Ну, или как вы хотите выводить данные об ошибке.

Comment: Скобки, конечно, наглядная вещь, но питон — это не хаваскрипт, здесь условия в скобки без необходимости не берут.

Comment: мне кажется так нагляднее, привык таким образом выделять.

Comment: Ну, кому как удобнее. Профессиональные питонисты никогда так не делают.

Comment: Специальнный синтаксис для двойных условий: `1 <= age <= 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно ошибку, то можно так:

```
if not (0 < int(input('Введите свой корректный возраст: ')) < 101):
    raise Exception('Ваш возраст некорректный!')
print('Круто!')
```

```
Введите свой корректный возраст: 128
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise Exception('Ваш возраст некорректный!')
Exception: Ваш возраст некорректный!
```